# How does one use rowspan to merge a <td> with position:absolute?

Tags: html, css

On a table I'd like the first 2 columns pinned in a fixed position, so I have to add `position:absolute` to the first 2 `<td>` tags. I want to merge the first row and the second row as well. So then I added `rowspan="2"` to both columns, unfortunately, `rowspan` isn't working on `<td>`s with `position:absolute`.

eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>td with position:absolute</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table{margin:auto; width: 1000px; overflow: visible;}
        td{text-align: center; background-color: yellow; border:1px solid black;}
        table div{width:200px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- You can remove the attribute "position:absolute" to see the result -->
                <td style="position:absolute;" rowspan="2"><div>Table head Row 1</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 2</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 3</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 4</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 5</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 6</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div>Table head Row 2</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 3</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 4</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 5</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 6</div></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot: Result with position:absolute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzorv.png)

[Plunker: `position: absolute` applied](http://plnkr.co/edit/PMJc7FZMG7CCoP4xQx78?p=preview)

[Screenshot: Result without position:absolute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo88Q.png)

[Plunker: `position: absolute` not applied](http://plnkr.co/edit/PMJc7FZMG7CCoP4xQx78?p=preview)

Comment: Please post CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: Demo without position absolute:http://plnkr.co/edit/PMJc7FZMG7CCoP4xQx78?p=preview

Comment: Demo with position absolute:http://plnkr.co/edit/gh9MNZ70lv53lQ6MM5kC?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  Here's why:

> Positioning and floating of table cells can cause them not to be table cells anymore, according to the rules in section 9.7. When floating is used, the rules on anonymous table objects may cause an anonymous cell object to be created as well.
> https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-CSS21-20060411/tables.html#q7

The `position:absolute` hack you're trying to use for sticky columns causes those positioned cels to be removed from the table and be drawn as block-level DOM elements instead.  Any table-specific markup such as rowspan will therefore no longer apply to those elements.

(Incidentally, you've omitted some code from your samples that are necessary for that hack to work: the table needs to be in a container with `overflow-x:scroll`, not `visible`.)

I think the best you can do here (short of redesigning to not need rowspans in the first place) is simulate rowspan by setting the height of that absolute-positioned table cell to the height of two table rows, and leaving an extra, non-positioned cell in the second row (which will be hidden behind the absolute-positioned one.)

Padding and margins will make this a bit imprecise and brittle, and it will of course only work if the table rows have a predictable height, but I'm not aware of any better approach.

```css
        .table {
          overflow: scroll;
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        td {
          text-align: center;
          background-color: yellow;
          border: 1px solid;
          height: 1.2em;
        }
        table div {
          width: 200px;
        }
        .sticky {
          position: absolute;
        }
        .tall {height: 2.8em}
```

```html
    <div class="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="sticky tall"><div>Table head Row 1</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 2</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 3</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 4</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 5</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 6</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><!-- will be hidden --></div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 2</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 3</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 4</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 5</div></td>
                <td><div>Table head Row 6</div></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, This is the perfect solution to my problem

Comment: Thanks for that great explanation. :) That  explains why I ended up using everything but `absolute`, I wish you were around to enlighten us earlier. :-\

Answer (score 0):

### Question:

How does one use rowspan to merge a `<td>` with `position:absolute`?

### Solution:

For some reason I couldn't figure out *why* `position: absolute` inhibits `rowspan`. Fortunately OP requested *how* not *why*.

> Made the table into 2 `inline-table`s.

- `#fixedTable` The first 2 columns is now a 2 column table.
- `#railTable` The remaining 6 columns are now the second table.

  > `#fixedTable` is:
- fixed at x(left):0, y(top):8px
- z-indexed at 1
- rowspaned on both columns

  > `#railTable` is:
- relatively positioned
- positioned at x(left): 415px which is the width of `#fixedTable`

  > The div that contains both tables `.tables` is:
- relatively positioned
- has a relative length that works with `overflow-x:scroll` that will allow `#railTable` to always slide it's full length left and right without ever being clipped (of course it would be limited in movement should the viewport become narrower than 415px which is the width of `#fixedtable`.

The trick is this:

```
      min-width: 100em;
```

So when `.tables` parent (i.e. `<body>`) decreases or increases so does the 100em's scaling. At default 100em = 1600px which is the width of both tables end to end (not counting border widths).

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rb5kYMo7CX6R4IlsGvaT?p=preview)

---

## **Old Answer**

---

## Changes

Changed the `<td>` to `position: relative` to keep it out of the flow like `absolute` and added `vertical-align: top;` to display the content better.

## Explanation

OP did not explain why a `<td>` needed to be positioned.

- Is the `position` property needed for `z-index`?

> If so, then `relative` is just as good as `absolute`.

- Is a specific x, y coordinate needed to move the `<td>`?

> If so, `relative` positioned elements are easier to move than `absolute` positioned elements.

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DQRrhrvNuMZo7w7k5Bkm?p=preview)

Comment: In fact,"for some reasons" is that i have to pinning the first column and the second column,so I tried to use "position:absolute" on `<td>` to ensure `<td>` located by the left screen and  it does works while the `<thead>` only have one row.

Comment: This is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QjAZsMPHP2AYU0xZpUIk?p=preview) Demo , 
but the first row have more than one row.